# Graph visualization: Leave gap between vertex and endpoint of edge

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

This is a nice graph:

```
g = CycleGraph[4];

Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}, 
 VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium, 
 EdgeShapeFunction -> 
  GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> 0.5}]]
```

[image]

But I want that the edges separated by an offset from the vertices. Is there a simple way to control this within `GraphElementData`, similarly to how I could control the curvature? I want also an arrow but if I add `"CarvedArrow"`, `"ArrowSize" -> .1` to `"CurvedArc"`, `"Curvature" -> 0.5` MA does'nt display anything.

Comment: Where are your `g`?

Comment: Please always put the code in a code block.  Select the code with the mouse and press the `{}` button on the toolbar.  I'm going to edit the post for you now, but please do this every time in the future when you post.  I see several downvotes, no doubt the lack of formatting contributed to that (as well as the lack of a concrete `g`, which I'm going to also edit into the post now).

Comment: Sorry not to have respected the standard I certainly was not correctly awaked. the graph was g = {a0 -> b0, b0 -> c0 , c0 -> d0, d0 -> a0}. Normaly I try to pay attention to this. I often fail.

Comment: OK, so the adding `CycleGraph` was exactly what you meant then.

Comment: Yes and the answer was perfect

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
ClearAll[esF]
esF[setback_: .2, as_: .1] := {Arrowheads[as], 
    Arrow[GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> 0.5}][##], setback]} &;

g0 = Graph[{a0 -> b0, b0 -> c0, c0 -> d0, d0 -> a0}, 
   VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}}, 
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium, 
   ImageSize -> 250];

SetProperty[g0, EdgeShapeFunction -> esF[]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Row[Labeled[SetProperty[g0, EdgeShapeFunction -> esF[#]], 
    "setback: " <> ToString[#], Top] & /@ {.2, {0, .2}, {.2, .4}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Row[Labeled[SetProperty[g0, EdgeShapeFunction -> esF[.2, #]], 
    "size: " <> ToString[#], Top] & /@ {.1, .2, Small, Large}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]